# Word Match Algorithm

Tags: c#, web-services, algorithm, barcode

We are designing a mobile application which reads barcodes of the products and get prices from 8 e-commerce sites. I am designing the web server side by C# that has all the logic and sends data to client by web service.

If I ask the price of the product by sending the barcode, everything is ok.
But most of the web site systems do not have barcode numbers in their database so I have to send them a Product Name and it MUST match somehow to get back the product details.

To get product name, i do a UPC lookup and get the product name from a web site.

But the problem starts at that moment. Every e-commerce site could have a different structure and different product name. How am I going to write an algorith that will go and parse e-commerce databases and bring me results. Do I really have to write a seperate data parser for every e-commerce site. Is there an algorithm that I can write.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, if I send every word in a product name in a string array, ecommerce website can search in their database word by word until they got one product result and return it to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to write that parser. I doubt there's any algorithm you could use, besides how this algorithm should work... (probably like your parser)

Answer (score 0):

1-One solution  would be store common product name in a database table so that you can store them in server memory as a static list and update the list by a Job at EOD.

2- Find some external web service which provide the prodcutname and use that service in your web service.

because , you just can't go each and every web site to parse the data.

Comment: Second choice is impossible as I said. Different e-commerce sites have different names on their databases. First choice is somehow manuel and would not optimize my solution. Thanks though for your nice reply.